Android Can I inject data into a shared object permanently at runtime, in other words alter the shared object once
I have an android app that uses several shared objects (C++) I wrote that hold specific and constant data. Linked at build. All is fine.
However there is one piece of data that is generated at runtime either dynamicaly or user input. I would like to then "store" this data into a shared object, once only, that is then loaded at subsequent runtimes presumably using System.load as is currently used for my other shared objects.
Currently I am storing this data encrypted in a SQLite table but for security reasons I would like to have it imbedded with a .so (injected once)
I understand bringing the data intio the .so at runtime would simply be a memory insert and would be lost on closing the app, so not different say to pulling the data from a database, bar it perhaps being more secure on the .so
The issue of course is how to alter the actual .so physically (inject data into it)
Is this posible ?
I have read the following but not sure if they address the need. Answer is the one with 99 upvotes ;
Is it possible to dynamically load a library at runtime from an Android application?
The above link suggests an alternative approach perhaps.
About 40 years ago I remember being able to inject data into a field within a built C library but I'm afraid that bit of knowledge has long since left me unfortunately.
I'm not an Android guy so struggling with this. Would appreciate any direction.

"for security reasons I would like to have it imbedded with a .so". Why would that add any security? An .so file is just a file like any other. There's nothing special about it that prevents people from inspecting its contents.

Isn't it a compiled C++ object that can be obfuscated ? My thinking was it just adds an additional hurdle for a hacker.
